# How to add images in UITableViewCells programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I need to add different images in `UITableViewCells` programmatically. How can I do that. I am trying some code. But the images are not displayed in `UITableViewCells`.
This is my code below.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    arrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"image.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png",@"image4.png",@"image5.png",@"image6.png",@"image7.png",@"image8.png" nil];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *identifier=@"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) 

    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    }

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 48)];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual code. This won't even compile.

Comment: Please check the images localtion. Go to Project Build Phases->Copy Bundle resources Add all images in the App bundle.

Comment: please help me any body....

Comment: plz my code use to 100% solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property of NSArray in your .h file

```
@property NSArray *imgArray;
```

synthesize in your .m file

```
@synthesize imgArray;
```

write this in your viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Initialize images...
    imgArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"yourFirstImageName.png", @"yourSecondImageName.png", @"yourThirdImageName.png",....., @"yourSeventhImageName.png", nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 48)]; // your cell's height should be greater than 48 for this.
        imgView.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
        imgView = nil;

        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

        lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lbl setTag:2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
        lblDisch = nil;
    }

    UIImageView *_imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    _imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    UILabel *_lbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    _lbl.text =  [arrFont objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // arrFont is your array
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your response.But i have seven images.how can i do this.

Comment: make seven imageview object with different tag.

Comment: ,thanks for your repsonse.But i cant understand ur  post.You mean creating seven UIImageviews and assign corresponding image?

Comment: .thanks for your response.But it is very lengthy process.I mean writing lot of code na?

Comment: your question is not clear. you want seven images in a cell or seven images in diffrent cells.

Comment: I want seven images in different cells.

Comment: thanks for your response.But you are not creating UIImageview programatically like " imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 48)];" how can u display images?

Comment: you can not change the frame of cell's image view but yes you can add image view to cell's content view.

Comment: how can i do this.please tell me.please give me solution

Comment: @thanks brother it is working good.But i got another problem.after image iam display some text in each UITableviewcell.The font is display on images. like "arrFont=[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"image1",@"image2"...@"image8"];"   cell.textLabel.text = [arrFont objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: but brother i got another problem. i am menction my problem on above post

Comment: wait...I am still here.

Comment: @Hi brother plz vote my question.The question is useful for some one.

Comment: see my updated ans and please let me know is it working or not.

Comment: Thanks brother it is working fine for me.please vote my question.i think so body useful to this one

Comment: ok sure.but i got another issue.the lable is displaying white color.

Comment: fine brother problem solve.no issues are there.thank u so much.have a good day.take care

Answer (score 3):

This is what you probably want:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.arrImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png",@"image4.png",@"image5.png",@"image6.png",@"image7.png",@"image8.png" nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
    }

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

**P.S.**: Next time, please make some effort on formatting the source code, explaining what is wrong, what have you tried, what would you like to accomplish. Thanks

Comment: thanks for your response.I am creating UIImageveiw programatically.so how to write the code.please once check my post

Comment: If you want to customise the appearance of ``UITableViewCell``'s ``imageView`` property then you should really make *custom* ``UITableViewCell`` *subclass* and add *custom* ``UIImageView`` *property* to it as a subview. You are currently using default ``UITableViewCell``'s ``imageView`` property which is **read-only**. [See more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_13).

Answer (score -2):

Create a @property of NSMutableArray in your .h file.

```
NSMutableArray *data;
```

Write This Code your .m file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"4.jpg",@"5.jpg",@"6.jpg",@"7.jpg",@"8.jpg",@"9.jpg",@"10.jpg",@"11.jpg",@"12.jpg",@"13.jpg",nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [data count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```